# Updating a SQL Server database using Entity Framework is not pulling in new tables

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

[image: New table]

I created a database in Azure and have it working just fine in my project.

I went to extend it today and discovered I'm unable to "Update database" in the `.edmx` file.

The new table has a PK.

So I created a very based test table and have the same issues with it.  This is the table I created:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] 
(
     [Id]         NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
     [Testcolumn] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
   ON [dbo].[TestTable]([Testcolumn] ASC);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
   ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
```

So again, after creating the table I go into the `.edmx` and click on update model from database and the new table(s) do not show up in Visual Studio 2017.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Update:
it gets even weirder.  I created a new model and updated from the database and the tables came down.  I still can't update the original model though.  I don't want the solution to be deleting the model and re-creating it because down the road that is not going to be a good idea.

Comment: This is brand spanking new... The version I have in source control is what I am working on... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to completely delete the model and recreate it.  That was the only thing that fixed it.  Nothing to do with the table configuration at all.

Answer (score -2):

EF requires that your table has s Primary key, and that is not the case.

Comment: Look closer it is; check out the constraint.  I'll also add in the image of the table in VS.  I right clicked on an existing, working table that was showing in entity and modified it with new names only.

Comment: I created a whole new table with no unique index, only the primary key with the same results.